How to prove if $M$ is sub-field of $N$, $S$ is the transcendental base $M$, then $N$ is algebraic expansion of $M(S)$?
I think to prove the theorem, I need to prove that if $S$ is transcendental over $M$ and $S'$ is a transcendental over of $M(S)$, then $S\cup S'$ is also transcendental over of $M$.
Please not that $M(S)$ is field generated by $S$ based on $m$
By assuming $S\cup S'$ is not transcendental over of $M$
Then I follow the definition assuming that there are:

A polynomial $f(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i\in P}\left(a_i\left(\prod_{j\in K_i}x_j^{k_{i,j}}\right)\right)\in M[x_1,...,x_n]$ that is none zero
$\{s_1,...,s_n\}\subset S'\cup S$

So that  $f(s_1,...,s_n)=0$ . Define the following:

$\{s_{i_1},...,s_{i_m}\}= S'\cap\{s_1,...,s_n\}$
$S^*=\{i_1,...,i_m\}$
$P^*=\left\{i\in P\big|K_i\cap S^*=\varnothing\right\}$
$f'(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i\in P-P^*}\left(\left(a_i\left(\prod_{j\in K_i-S^*}s_j^{k_{i,j}}\right)\right)\left(\prod_{j\in K_i\cap S^*}x_j^{k_{i,j}}\right)\right)+\sum_{i\in P^*}a_i\left(\prod_{j\in K_i}s_j^{k_{i,j}}\right)$

Obviously that $f'(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a polynomial in $M(S)[x_1,...,x_n]$ now how can I prove that it is a non zero function on $M(S)[x_1,...,x_n]$??

Please include your definition of transcendence base. Often a transcendence base of $N/M$ is defined as a subset $S$ of $N$ which is algebraically independent over $M$ such that $N/M(S)$ is algebraic.

@blargoner  transcendence base is the local maximum set of algebraically independent over $M$
